# Kill this user for being a 1 rep spammer

Tags: bug

I think this user: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/115420/sarah-hanes should have their account deleted because they posted 2 spam posts. They are a 1 rep spammer who should be deleted outright.

Comment: "kill this user" sounds bad..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The user has been destroyed. Please note that **you should not start a meta thread over single instances of spam**. Just flag the posts as spam and the user will typically be automatically blocked and later cleaned up.

If there's a need for the user to be destroyed for other reasons, just flag the post.

Comment: I can't flag it after it has been deleted as spam

Comment: @Asadefa Users who can view deleted posts still can I believe (though they still won't see the post if it was marked spam), but the broader point is that there's usually no real need to. If a post was removed as spam the user will be marked as a spam account and automatically [prevented from posting again.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997)